# Calling partial view table redirect to login instead of staying on the same page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that will have lots of data, so I'm trying to limit data to 4. On clicking the Next button, should return following 4 data, etc. My problems arises when the next button is clicked. The partial view showing the next data shows for a moment and I am quickly redirected to the login page

This is for ASP.Net Core 2.1 MVC project

Controller_Code

```
public IActionResult Employees()
{
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = 1;
    ViewBag.LastPage =
    Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(_Context.Employee.ToList().Count)/4);
    var value = _context.Employee.ToList();
    return View(value.OrderBy(c=>c.Id).Take(4))
}
```

Controller_Post_Code

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResults Employees(int CurrentPage, int LastPage)
{
    ViewBag.CurrentPage = CurrentPage;
    ViewBag.LastPage = LastPage;
    var value = _context.Employee.ToList();
    return PartialView("_EmployeeList", 
    value.OrderBy(c=>c.Id).Skip((CurrentPage - 1)*4).Take(4));
}
```

My Index Next and Previous Button are as follows
I want to refresh/page only a partial view, not the whole pageload

```
<div id="EmployList">
    <partial name ="_EmployeeList", model="Model"/>
</div>

<form asp-controller="Employ" asp-action="Employees"
    data-ajax="true"
    data-ajax-method="post"
    data-ajax-mode="replace"
    data-ajax-update="#EmployList">
  <input type="hidden" id="CurrentPage" value="@ViewBag.CurrentPage"/> 
  <input type="hidden" id="LastPage" value="@ViewBag.LastPage"/>
</form>


<div>
    <button asp-controller="Employ" asp-action="Employees" id="Next"> Next 
    </button>
    <button asp-controller="Employ" asp-action="Employees" id="Previous"> Previous 
    </button>
</div>
```

Script Info

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#Previous").click(function(){
  if(CalculateAndSetPage("Previous"))
     $("form").submit();
  });
$("#Next").click(function(){
  if(CalculateAndSetPage("Next"))
     $("form").submit();
  });
});

function CalculateAndSetPage(movingType){
    var currentPage = parseInt($("#CurrentPage").val());
    var lastPage = parseInt($("#lastPage").val());
    if(currentPage == 1 && movingType == "Previous")
       return false;
    if(currentPage==lastPage && movingType=="Next")
       return false;
    if (movingType == "Previous")
       currentPage--;
    if (movingType == "Next")
       currentPage++;
    $("#CurrentPage").val(currentPage);
     return true;
 }
```

When I run the same code on the project that doesn't require authentication, it works.
I am expecting to press next and it shows next 4 results but it show results for a moment and automatically redirects to login

Can someone who knows how to resolve this help please. Thank you :)

Comment: Have you tried using a normal input button? It seems weird to have a asp-controller attached to your button and at the same time submit the form with javascript.

Comment: I tried that, but I get same results. The code I posted is an updated one after some people suggested but still doesn't give required results

Comment: The aim is to submit and change only the PartialView, not do the whole page load

Comment: If you want to do a partial page change, you'll have to use $.post, call a partial view controller and put the resulting html in the page.